# Sum of product price in Product List and key is product type and value is Sum of Prices of product type using streams

Tags: java, stream

Input: List of Products.

Product Object:id,productType,price,desc

Output: Map<String, String>

key is product type and value is sum of the price

Comment: Find more information about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: why sum of the price is String in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the price is integer and appropriate getters are available in `Product` class, a combination of `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.summingInt` help resolve this task.

```java
Map<String, Integer> totalPriceByType = products.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupBy(
        Product::getProductType, 
        Collectors.summingInt(Product::getPrice)
));
```

Comment: Can always do a `collectingAndThen` on the downstream if a `String` value is really required.